# <a> click event not firing from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a requirement to update data without redirecting to another page. In my controller I have a method with a return type of `void` which updates the data. In my partial view I have an `<a>` element. On click of the link I am calling the above method which returns `void` to my jQuery file.

```
<div id="Footer">
    <a href="#" id="MarkAllRead">Mark All Read</a>
</div>
```

```js
$(".MarkAllRead").click(function () {
    alert('click');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/MarkNotification",
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        datatype: "text",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#ncount").hide();
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(result.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

```csharp
public void MarkNotificationAsRead()
{
    db.Notifications.ToList().ForEach(n => n.Status = true);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the AJAX call is not getting fired. On click of the link I want to call the above method which returns `void` from my jQuery file.

Comment: Only one #MarkAllRead  element. No errors . Click event is not getting fired.   alert('click');  is not getting fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in your jQuery selector.

```
$(".MarkAllRead").click(function () {
```

should become this: (use a # instead of a dot - dot is for class nd # is for id)

```
$("#MarkAllRead").click(function () {
```

Comment: I have tried # already. But it ddnt make any difference

Comment: Did changing to the # cause the Alert('click') to fire? If not - perhaps you are running your script before your link is created on the page and so it fails to find it.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I have moved my ajax call to that particular view and it is firing the event now. Other than moving the code to particular view is ther any other way/perfect solution.I would mark it as answer as it gives me the idea to fix.

Comment: Not sure if you are familiar with the idea of having your code executed only when the page is loaded/ready:  [link](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I have the script reference in my layout to render the script. the particular portion notification is a popup from the  menu which will be loaded when i click on the the count image. So as you said my script file renedered before the partial view loaded(the menu dropdown). Thanks for your response ans it solved my problem.

Comment: you are running your script before your link is created on the page and so it fails to find it. - Problem is solved with the help of this comment. hence marking it as answer

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting by `class`, when the element has an `id`. Change this:

```
$(".MarkAllRead").click(function () {
```

to this:

```
$("#MarkAllRead").click(function () {
```

Comment: If the problem is caused by a typo, why didn't you vote to close it as such?

Comment: What makes you think I haven't?

Comment: Well then why did you answer an off-topic question?

Comment: Trying to be helpful for the OP.

Comment: Hiya.. I am not getting the problem with the question. I am not that experienced with stackoverflow. Please correct me if anything wrong with the query

Comment: @jubi given what you've shown the answer should fix the problem. Can you setup a http://jsfiddle.net which shows the behaviour you see?

Comment: You can be helpful in comments, too.  By answering off-topic questions, you're potentially preventing the Roomba from cleaning them up automatically (questions with positively scored or accepted answers don't get deleted automatically).  There's also a chance that the typo was a copypasta error.